# Can you copy the content of a method intro a StringStream?

Tags: c++, string, methods, stringstream

For Example:

```
void Display()
{
    cout << "Hello World" << endl;
}

stringstream ss;
```

How can i make the `display` method input into the `ss` stringstream?

Comment: ss << "Hello World"` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// Save the old cout's streambuf 
streambuf* old = cout.rdbuf();

ostringstream oss;

// replace cout's streambuf with the ostringstream's
cout.rdbuf(oss.rdbuf());

// Call Display
Display();

// Restore the old cout
cout.rdbuf(old);
```

Explanation in the comments itself.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers.  I am a very new programmer and i have no knowledge of streambuf or any streams in fact.